# How do I solve this Memgraph SSL connection error?

Tags: python, docker, memgraphdb

I am trying to run `memgraph` 1.2.0 - with `docker` and getting the following SSL connection error -

`ERROR services/memgraph/tests/collapse_test.py::test_incorrect_pseudo_node - neobolt.exceptions.SecurityError: Failed to establish secure connection to '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER]`

How can I solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems like Memgraph is not configured to use SSL, and the client is trying to make the SSL connection.

If that's the case, and Neo4j's Python driver is used, the client should be configured with disabled encryption:

```
from neo4j import GraphDatabase, basic_auth
driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost:7687",
                              auth=basic_auth("", ""),
                              encrypted=False)
```

Which version of the Neo4j's Python driver are you using? Newer versions of the driver (> 4.0) should have the encryption disabled by default.

Comment: Thanks! That solved the problem :D I'm using the Neo4j 3.5 Python driver.